# VMware tools could not locate components on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vmware, vmware-tools

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 host and I tried to install VMware tools on MacOS 10.15 guest.

When I tried to press "Install VMware tools", It shows `Could not find component on update server. Contact VMware Support or your system administrator`.

I tried searching it on Google and most posts told me to find it on https://packages.vmware.com/tools/releases/latest/ but it doesn't provide VMware tools for Ubuntu 20.04.

I would like to know is there any way to fix this or should I find a Windows machine to install it?

Comment: Did you try what it said and contact Vmware support?

Comment: @David yes but VMware support just mentioned users can install VMware tools at a option list on top-left corner. I also checked the forum but the links are broken.